# Invariant Violation error during testing react component which consumes prop from context api

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-context

I am new to jest and enzyme and I am running into some Invariant Violation errors when testing a react component which consumes a prop from react’s context api. I am familiar with Invariant Violation errors and its possible causes, however, in this context I am stuck. Some advice is very appreciated. Here is a minimal code setup just for demonstration purposes. I am running
"enzyme": "3.7.0", 
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.6.0",
"jest": "23.6.0".

Note, the code below works just fine, however, the trouble only starts when i try to test MyComponent.jsx.

index.jsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MyComponentWithContext from "./MyComponent";

const testValue = 'test value';

export const MyContext = React.createContext(testValue);

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <MyComponentWithContext/>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyContext.Provider value={testValue}>
        <App/>
    </MyContext.Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root') || document.createElement('div')
)
```

MyComponent.jsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {MyContext} from './';

export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    getContextValue() {
        return this.props.testValue
    }
    render() {
        return <div>{this.getContextValue()}</div>;
    }
}

const MyComponentWithContext = () => (
    <MyContext.Consumer>
        {testValue => <MyComponent testValue={testValue}/>}
    </MyContext.Consumer>
)

export default MyComponentWithContext;
```

When i try to test MyComponent like so:

MyComponent.unit.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import {MyComponent} from '../MyComponent';

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
    const testValue = 'test value';
    it('should return test value', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent testValue={testValue}/>);
        expect(wrapper.instance().getContextValue()).toEqual(testValue);
    });

});
```

This gives me the following error:

Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `App`.

```
| ReactDOM.render(
         |          ^
      18 |     <MyContext.Provider value={testValue}>
      19 |         <App/>
      20 |     </MyContext.Provider>,
```

Comment: I suppose that a component is undefined because of circular dependency. And the real problem is that there shouldn't be circular dependency at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReactDOM.render(...)` shouldn't be evaluated in unit tests. Modules are improperly organized. *index.js* provides side effects which should be avoided in unit tests, it also has unnecessary circular dependency with *MyComponent.js* that could be avoided.

```
export const MyContext = React.createContext(testValue);
```

should be moved to separate module, so component module could import it directly.